# How Handle GZIP compression JSON on HTTP Trigger in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My JIRA tenant is sending a webhook to a Logic App HTTP Trigger.

```
 {
            "created": "2020-03-26T09:33:22.388+0100",
            "updated": "2020-03-26T09:33:22.388+0100",
            "started": "2020-03-26T09:32:19.415+0100",
            "timeSpent": "1m",
            "timeSpentSeconds": 60,
            "id": "10017",
            "issueId": "10026"
 }
```

I have tested sending this message to Logic Apps using Postman and I receive the data fine in my Logic App. However when I try the real thing, and the webhook is sent from JIRA, the HTTP message is received but there isn't any Body included, cf image [Zero contents?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLhdC.png)

I have the feeling this may have got something to do with Logic Apps HTTP trigger not able to support GZIP/Deflate compression, cf image [gzip deflate compression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJlHg.png)

Does Logic Apps HTTP trigger support compression? If it doesn't what would be a nice workaround, can I create some kind of Azure function listener instead?

**UPDATE**

I have been able to isolate the problem a bit more, its not related to compression it seems.  Its related to a mismatch between real content payload size and header content-size.

JIRA webhooks sends for example a payload with size 100, but the header that is sent along with it, tells its 76 (for some weird reason), and subsequently Logic Apps CUTS off the message returning the following message;

{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
        "message": "The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \". Path 'worklog.updateAuthor.avatarUrls.32x32', line 27, position 119.'."
    }
}

No solution yet...